# How to suppress devskim issue in a json file

Tags: security, static-analysis

As comments don't work in Json file, what's the method to suppress Devskim issues in Json file?

Tried the following solution:
Create a new file called .devskim in the root directory of your project if it doesn't already exist. Inside the .devskim file, add a suppressions property with an array of objects representing the issues you want to suppress. For example, to suppress a DevSkim issue with the rule ID DS137138, you would add the following to your .devskim file: Json.
Copy code
`{   "suppressions": [     {       "Id": "code number",       "justification": "Suppressing issue in file."     }   ] }`

Answer (score 0):

My team at Microsoft wrote and maintains DevSkim. DevSkim uses inline suppressions described in the [VS Code Plugin readme](https://github.com/microsoft/DevSkim/tree/main/DevSkim-VSCode-Plugin#suppressions) and elsewhere in the project docs. Within the IDE, you should be able to click on the squiggly and choose to suppress the issue; in text, it looks like this:

```c
bool result = MD5(userString); // DevSkim: ignore DS126858 until 2023-06-28
bool result = MD5(userString); // DevSkim: ignore DS126858 Required by spec.
bool result = MD5(userString); // DevSkim: ignore DS126858
```

If you'd like to ignore a certain rule across all files, you can do that through the settings UI within the IDE. For example, within VS Code:

[image: VS Code UI showing ignoring a certain rule]

The CLI also supports these options.

If you'd like to propose an additional suppression mechanism (a `.devskim` or similar file with a structured list of suppressions), please [submit an feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/devskim) or consider contributing a pull request.